# How to get bad record details using FAILFAST mode in pyspark while reading a CSV file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

My requirement is to fail the spark application even if there is one bad record in the input csv file. FAILFAST mode gives that option, but I am not able to get which record(s) caused the failure. Is there anyway to get bad record details in FAILFAST mode? Also, please advise any work around in case this is not possible in FAILFAST.

Note: I can use PERMISSIVE mode with columnNameOfCorruptRecord or the option badRecordsPath and based on the result I can programmatically stop the execution. But here the data will be processed first causing an unnecessary resource utilization. Hence I am trying to use FAILFAST.

Comment: Less than ideal, and not really a solution to your question but I avoid the double processing of columnNameOfCorruptRecord by caching the result.